# Replacing nonbreaking spaces (%A0) in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've got some values in a `varchar` column that are separated by nonbreaking spaces (urlencoded `%A0` instead of `%20`). I'm trying to replace them with spaces, but can't seem to get the syntax right:

```
select regexp_replace('hello world', E'\xa0', ' ')
```

What is the correct way to encode the character in a Postgres `regexp_replace` function? Or, is there a better way to do the replacement?

Comment: You don't need `regexp_replace()`. `replace()` is enough

Comment: `0xA0` is a non-breaking-space in ISO-8859-1 (AKA Latin-1), are you sure that's the right encoding for your database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you share the syntax that would work with the character code and replace? That's the part that I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you

```
select replace('Hello world', '\xa0', '')
```

Ref [Postgresql (Current) Section 9.4. String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: Not sure why, but this expression does not replace u+a0 in my string.

Answer (score 7):

Replacing `'\xa0'` didn't work for me, possibly because my strings were in UTF-8 rather than Latin1 or other where the character is encoded directly as `A0`. (`U+A0` is encoded with bytes `C2 A0` in UTF-8)

I found it more practical to replace it as a code point (`U+A0`) rather than as the encoded bytes (`C2 A0` or `A0`):

```
select replace('456321 ', E'\u00a0', '')  -- value is E'456321\u00a0'
```